# Can't set HPE BootRom password on newer versions

Tags: switch, password-reset, hpe

Could someone please explain to me where can I find option to set BootRom password in newer Comware switch like HP 3600 v2? The menu looks like this:

```
1. Download application file to flash
2. Select application file to boot
3. Display all files in flash
4. Delete file from flash
5. Restore to factory default configuration
6. Enter BootRom upgrade menu
7. Skip current system configuration
8. Reserved
9. Set switch startup mode
0. Reboot
```

Not like the other switches like 3com 4500, where I had this option visible:

```
1. Download application file to flash
2. Select application file to boot
3. Display all files in flash
4. Delete file from flash
5. Modify bootrom password
6. Enter bootrom upgrade menu
7. Skip current configuration file
8. Set bootrom password recovery
9. Set switch startup mode
```

When it boots after ctrl+b it only states that no password is needed, press enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short explanation: **The feature has been removed** in BootRom versions prior to 712.

It seems this change hasn't been clearly documented as there isn't a history of BootRom release notes, and the HP(E) installation guides are designed for the version installed on purchase: you can only see the menu and the explanations for a single version, with only indirect hints like:

> If password recovery capability is disabled, you can upgrade the Boot
>   ROM to only Version 160 or higher.

The reason behind this decision is best explained in HPE Support Center [mmr_kc-0133804](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0133804). The question is for HP 5500, but the explanation most likely applies to all switches with BootRom:

> **SYMPTOM:** After upgrading software to the latest version there is no
>   longer the option to "Modify bootrom password" or "Set bootrom
>   password recovery" in the Boot Menu
>
> **CAUSE:** This option was removed per HPE in bootrom versions prior to 712
>   although version 707 has the option for the bootrom password . It was
>   determined to be a security risk and backdoor into the switch via the
>   switch mac-address and the software program to create a super
>   password. Bootrom version 712 and later no longer support the option
>   for the bootrom password
>
> **FIX:** none

Starting the switch with the factory default configuration (`7. Skip current system configuration`) is a one-time operation that requires physical access to the switch, so having *bootrom password recovery* enabled is not a remotely exploitable feature.